# Validity of the changeset. What would happen if components related to a changeset removed in the org?

Tags: deployment, sandbox, change-set, production

I have created a changeset in the sandbox and upload it to the production org. In the production org, I have validated and confirmed that will deploy in that org without any issues.

Now, my question is, I want to remove the components in the sandbox that I have included in the changeset. If I try to deploy the changeset which I already validated in the production, will it deploy successfully? Please advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer- yes

Once a Change Set is successfully uploaded from source and is available in destination org, deleting component part of original Change Set from source org would not affect the Change Set in destination org; as it was already sent.

In case you want to deploy any modified components, you would need to clone the Change Set in your source org and upload it again to destination org.